# Spyder IDE Font on File names too big

Tags: python, anaconda, ide, spyder

I was recently given a new surface tablet as a work laptop. When I installed and opened Spyder, I noticed that the font on the file names in the top banner was frustratingly large. See picture below. How do I reduce this font?

[image]

Comment: all the other time's I've used spyder this hasn't happened

Comment: Maybe checking the preferences for HDPI screens could help. The preferences are in `Preferences > Application > Interface > Screen resolution`

Comment: I am running into this issue as well. The issue exists both within the anacondas distribution and stand-alone installation.